# If/else em Ruby

Tags: ruby

Sou bem iniciante em Ruby e enquanto praticava fazendo alguns exercícios aqui me deparei com um erro que não entendi ainda como ocorre.

Bom, o erro é o seguinte: Tem uma comparação de um numero digitado pelo usuário, que se esse numero for maior ou igual a 65, retorne uma mensagem 'x', mas quando digito um numero bem inferior, ele ao invés de me mostrar a mensagem y, ele me retorna 'x' do mesmo jeito.

Segue o codigo:

```
puts'Por favor, digite sua idade: '
idade = gets.chomp

if idade >= '18' and idade < '65'
    print'Legal, você é maior de idade, ja pode ser preso.'
elsif idade < '17'
    print'Que pena, você ainda é menor de idade.'
else idade >= '65'
    print'Você ja é um idoso.'
end
```

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com mais detalhes sobre as comparações de string

Answer (score 3):

Veja a diferença do uso do else e do elsif nas duas versões:

```
puts'Por favor, digite sua idade: '
idade = gets.chomp
idade = idade.to_i

if idade >= 18 and idade < 65
    print'Legal, você é maior de idade, ja pode ser preso.'
elsif idade < 18
    print'Que pena, você ainda é menor de idade.'
elsif idade >= 65
    print'Você ja é um idoso.'
end
```

Pra usar else apenas, teria que ser algo assim:

```
puts'Por favor, digite sua idade: '
idade = gets.chomp
idade = idade.to_i

if idade >= 18 and idade < 65
    print'Legal, você é maior de idade, ja pode ser preso.'
elsif idade < 18
    print'Que pena, você ainda é menor de idade.'
else 
    print'Você ja é um idoso.'
end
```

Notar que seu código original vai dar problema se puser exatamente 17, por isso arrumei o primeiro elsif.

Também acrescentei esta linha para termos certeza que você está usando inteiros:

```
idade = idade.to_i
```

E como você mesmo notou, as aspas não são mais necessárias. O problema de strings, é que por exemplo, o '9' é maior que '18', pois com strings trata-se de ordem alfabética e não numérica, atrapalhando os resultados. Da mesma forma, '7' é maior que '65' nesse contexto.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu tinha respondido o comment, e complementei a pergunta neste sentido: "E como você mesmo notou, as aspas"... De qq forma, grato pelo aviso, poderia ser que eu nao tivesse visto ;) (vou apagar esse comment depois)